# Strange issue with integration test

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-boot-test, completable-future, mockmvc

1. @Sql at tested class

```
INSERT INTO bankdemo.bills(id, is_active, balance, currency, account_id)
VALUES('0', '1', '0.00', 'RUB', '0');
```

2. green test shows that Bill with id == 0 presents in DB

```
    @Test
    void can_change_bill_status() throws Exception {
        
        mockMVC.perform(get("/bills/status/{id}", "0"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("false")));
    }
```

3. but next one suddenly fails

```
    @Test
    void can_export_data_2_csv_file() throws Exception {
        
        mockMVC.perform(get("/operations/print/{id}", "0"))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE));
    }
```

with CompletionException: EntityNotFoundException: Target bill with id: 0 not found

Inside controller's method under test of p.3 taking Bill from DB by using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

```
    CompletableFuture<BillResponseDTO> futureBill = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync
            (() -> {try {return billService.getBillDTO(id);}
                    catch(EntityNotFoundException exc) {log.error(exc.getMessage(), exc);
                    throw new CompletionException(exc);}
            }, executorService);
    BillResponseDTO bill = futureBill.join();
```

probably this is the case but how to test this part of code properly?

The programm itself and slice @WebMvcTest using mocked access to DB are fine.
Spring Boot 2.6.6

**Addition:**

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        final int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(cores);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(cores * 2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(cores * 10);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

Also there is another task running async at this particular method of controller and it does not cause any problems at all:

```
        CompletableFuture<List<OperationResponseDTO>> futureOperations =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> operationService.getAll(id), executorService);
```

Comment: `GET /bills/status/{id}` and `GET /operations/print/{id}` are two different endpoints. It does not make sense how having 2XX as a response code on the first one should impact the latter. Literally you are asking to find a bug in your `/operations/print` endpoint.

Comment: Well, there's also another green test-method proving that Bill entity with exact id==0 was successfully persisted before the whole test class execution started. So I wonder is there any special trick required to write correct test code for methods which are using CompletableFuture? Because I don't see any reason for this EntityNotFoundException to appear...

Comment: I advise you getting rid of extra stuff around the CompletableFuture. Just create a very simple method which returns a constant value after a delay, then try testing. At this point the root cause of your issue is not clear.

Comment: When I do comment out this part of CompletableFuture acting from supplyAsync to join() and replace it with direct call BillResponseDTO bill = billService.getBillDTO(id) test becomes green.

Comment: @V-CHO spring's transactions are bound to thread, so that is expected one threads do not see modifications performed by other threads. In your case there are two options: 1. `@SqlConfig(transactionMode=TransactionMode.ISOLATED)` - will definitely affect other tests and you will need to start thinking about how to prepare test data. 2. make `executorService` "synchronous" for testing - i.e. execute task in calling thread, that is not clear how you build `executorService`, so, can't suggest anything (`SyncTaskExecutor` could be an option btw)- that may cause deadlocks in your application.

Comment: I have updated my question with Executor's bean code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was not about CompletableFuture but with behave of Spring Boot tests using H2 database. SQL scripts are initializing data strangely depending at which stage they get invoked (during start-up or by @SQL above test class or method declaration).